# Spring boot parent prevents resources:resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have a spring boot maven project with a property file in which I need to replace the property value for `spring.cloud.config.server.git.username` and `spring.cloud.config.server.git.password` properties using mvn resources:resources, but the values are not replaced as I expected.
To try to find the cause I created a small project that only contains the property file and pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>resource-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>resource-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <a.name>placholder</a.name>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Executing `mvn resources:resources -Da.name="some name"` with the above pom, the `${a.name}` is not replaced, but when I remove the spring boot parent from the pom, the `${a.name}` is replaced.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong here?

This is the content of the property file:

```
Hello ${a.name}.
```

Comment: You should check the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-properties-and-configuration. which states to use `@a.name@` instead ....calling resource goal intentionally?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks that did the trick. Would you please add your comment as answer, that way I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-properties-and-configuration) it is stated that you have to use `@a.name@` instead of `${a.name}`.